# Help Enabling Web Part Properties

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, chrome

I added a web part to a page I created for a site collection sub-site having the project template. I am able to add a web part (Media & Content -> Page Viewer), but the Web Part Properties button on the Web Part tab is not enabled to edit its properties. The web part has focus and I am logged in as the administrator. What is required to enable the Web Part Properties button?

SharePoint 2013 SP1 Enterprise Edition, Windows Server 2012 R2, IE 11.

Comment: Are you in edit page mode? Have you selected the web part by clicking the check box?

Comment: i am in edit page mode. i am not sure to what check box you are referring. i have selected the web part by clicking on the page viewer (which is shown as a rectangle). then the Web Part tab appears in the ribbon. but when i select the Web Part tab, ALL of the buttons are disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is causing because of browser issues. Try to change the browser and see if you are able to reproduce this issue.

This [link](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/233685.aspx) suggests the issue is with SharePoint and IE11

Comment: u da man!!! when you mentioned browsers, i remembered that i had problems with ssrs admin and had to add the site to compatibility list. the same action fixed it for this problem. thanks again!!!

Comment: Nice to hear your issue is resolved. Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to go to Internet Explorer Compatibility View Settings add your web site URL
it will solve your problem